# Why does this Swift RegEx match "e1234"?

Tags: regex, swift

Here's the regular expression:

```
    let legalStr = "(?:[eE][\\+\\-]?[0-9]{1,3})?$"
```

Here's the invocation:

```
        if let match = sender.stringValue.rangeOfString(legalStr, options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
            print("\(sender.stringValue) is legal")
        }
        else {
            print( "\(sender.stringValue) is not legal")
        }
```

If I type garbage, like "abcd" is returns illegal string.
If I type something like "e123" it returns legal string.
(note that the empty string is also legal.)
However, if I type "e1234" it still returns "legal". I'd expect it to return "not legal". Am I missing something here?  BTW, note the "$" at the end of the regular expression. The three digits should appear at the end of the string.

If it's not immediately clear, the source of the string is a text edit box.

Comment: Note that removing the trailing "?" causes the code to work as expected, though it doesn't allow empty strings at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is only anchored at the end, and matches the empty string. So any string at all will match successfully by just matching your pattern as an empty string at the end.

Add a `^` to the front to anchor it on that side, too.